# Convergence of series in a Hilbert Space

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

I'm hoping for some help on the following question.   I haven't gotten very far:

Let $\{h_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of vectors in a Hilbert space $H$ with the property that $(h_n-h_m)\perp h_m$ for $n\geq m$.  Show that

$$
\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{h_n}{||h_n||^2} \  \text{ converges in $H$ }\iff \sum_{n\geq1}\frac{n}{||h_n||^2}<\infty.
$$

Playing with the given property it's easy to show $(h_n,h_m)=||h_m||^2$ for $n\geq m$, and hence via Cauchy-Schwarz we can get $||h_n||\geq ||h_m||$ for $n\geq m$.  Unfortunately, beyond this, I am stuck.  Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the ideas that should be used.

---

Let us do some massage to what we have.

$$||h_{n+1}-h_n||^2=||h_{n+1}||^2+||h_n||^2-2(h_{n+1},h_n)=||h_{n+1}||^2-||h_n||^2$$

We also have, for $n\geq m$,

$$\begin{align}(h_{n+1}-h_n,h_{m+1}-h_m)&=(h_{n+1},h_{m+1})+(h_n,h_m)-(h_{n+1},h_m)-(h_n,h_{m+1})\\&=||h_{m+1}||^2+||h_m||^2-||h_m||^2-||h_{m+1}||^2\\&=0\end{align}$$

for $n\geq m$

$$(h_{n+1}-h_n,h_{m})=(h_{n+1},h_m)-(h_n,h_m)=||h_m||^2-||h_m||^2=0$$.

and for $n>m$

$$(h_{m+1}-h_m,h_{n})=(h_{m+1},h_n)-(h_m,h_n)=||h_{m+1}||^2-||h_m||^2.$$

---

To simplify notation let us put $||h_n||^2=r_n$

We use the following transformation of the sum we have ($\sum \frac{h_n}{r_n}$)

I will only do it with a small partial sum.

$$\frac{h_1}{r_1}+\frac{h_2}{r_2}+\frac{h_3}{r_3}=h_1\left(\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{1}{r_2}+\frac{1}{r_3}\right)+(h_2-h_1)\left(\frac{1}{r_2}+\frac{1}{r_3}\right)+(h_3-h_2)\left(\frac{1}{r_3}\right)$$

You know, summation by parts (Abel's transformation) taking the factor $h_n$ for the finite difference and $\frac{1}{r_n}$ for the summation.

Now we compute norm squared and bound it with (use for this the computation of $||h_{n+1}-h_n||^2$ and the orthogonality of the differences)

$$\begin{align}r_1\left(\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{1}{r_2}+\frac{1}{r_3}\right)^2&+(r_2-r_1)\left(\frac{1}{r_2}+\frac{1}{r_3}\right)^2+(r_3-r_2)\left(\frac{1}{r_3}\right)^2=\\&=r_1[(...)^2-(...)^2]+r_2[(...)^2-(...)^2]+r_3[(...)^2]\\&=\left(\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{1}{r_2}+\frac{1}{r_3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{r_2}+\frac{1}{r_3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{r_3}\right)\\&=\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{2}{r_2}+\frac{3}{r_3}\end{align}$$

where the line with the $(...)^2$ is to give an idea on how to do the simplification, i.e. by opening the parentheses that have the differences of $r_i$'s. But you can do it in any way you like.